# Magento 2 import product attribute type fixed product tax

Tags: magento, magento2

How can i import a products with an attributes of type "Fixed Product Tax" ?

When i export a csv from the back office i don't have any attribute of type "Fixed Product Tax"

Answer (score 0):

As per this article here: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-fixed-product-tax-magento-2.html

Step 1: Activate Fixed Product Tax in Stores > Settings > Configurations > Sales > Tax

Step 2: You'll need to create the FTP attribute:

On the Admin Panel, Stores > Attributes > Products.

In the upper-right corner, hit the Add New Attribute, and do as the following:

- Fill the Default Label for the attribute.
- In the Catalog Input Type
  for Store Owner field, select **Fixed Product Tax** option.

Then it should appear in your export with the attribute code you provided. You can also use this attribute code to import the value.

Comment: Yes i doing that but when i exporting my products i don't have any FPT attributs